# SQLNCLI syntax error when using OPENROWSET in SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql-server, connection-string, oledb, openrowset, sqlncli

### SQLNCLI syntax when using OPENROWSET

We have been using this syntax when using OpenRowset to collect data from other SQL Server instances.

`SELECT a.* FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=MyServer;Database=Tasks; User Id=sa;Password=myPassword;','SELECT * FROM Patients') As a`;

I am facing following some errors.

> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI" for linked server "(null)" returned message "Invalid authorization specification".
> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI" for linked server "(null)" returned message "Invalid connection string attribute".
> The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. Authentication failed.
> Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "(null)".

Comment: Out of interest, why are you using SQLNCLI when it is deprecated? Why not use MSOLEDBSQL?

Comment: /waveshand Those are not the [connection string parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/applications/using-connection-string-keywords-with-sql-server-native-client) you're looking for. Try `UID` and `PWD` instead of `User ID` and `Password`.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my error using following query.

I replaced SQLCLI with MSDASQL and wrote driver name as SQL Server.

```
select a.* from openrowset('MSDASQL', 'Driver={SQL SERVER}; Server=MYINSTANCE;UID=mySQLUser; PWD=*******;', 'select * from sys.databases') as a
```